# Missing Get Method in V6.0.10.0

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I just started using the FB Csharp SDK and installed the latest version of the SDK using nuget. (Am creating a WP7 App).

I am following the instructions at http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-First-Facebook-Application-v6.aspx to understand the SDK.

```
FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient(FB_AppAccessToken);
```

However, I can't find the Get method thats been widely quoted in most of the example. Have I installed the wrong version or am I missing something very fundamental? I am newbie so any help/pointers is/are deeply appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronous methods are not available in Windows Phone, Silverlight and WinRT (Windows Metro Style) application.

Use async versions, `XAsync` or `XTaskAsync` methods such as `GetAsync` or `GetTaskAsync` methods.